# Getting such type of exception when tring to send email and i am using eclipse, javamail api 1.4.2. so can anybody help me

Tags: java, email

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/Socket;
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:162)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
    at lms.SendFileEmail.mailling(SendFileEmail.java:49)
    at lms.LmsMainController.doGet(LmsMainController.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: check for your jar files. They should be in classpath.

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_27625646.html) may it helps. May you have a wrong version of mail.jar or smtp.jar in your classpath

Answer (score 2):

`SocketFetcher` API has two overloaded methods with following signature

```
static Socket getSocket(String host, int port, Properties props, String prefix)


static Socket getSocket(String host, int port, Properties props,
                        String prefix,boolean useSSL)
```

Both these methods return a `Socket` object. You should be either calling the method with the wrong signature or most probably an older version of jar file with the class not having the new / updated method may be your problem. Please check you have the correct version of the jar getting loaded first by the Classloader

Comment: Thanks for reply but let you know, I attached javamail api v1.4.5 and also activation.jar , although its giving same eror at runtime... please find a simple way so that i could get ride of this problem... thx

Comment: Please check if there is also another version of jar getting loaded prior to these jars

Comment: would you please give me the jar file via email or link of exact  required jar file which will suitable for my application..., one think which should tell you about this code that the same code is working properly on IDE-netbeans but not on eclipse.  please reply and thanks in advanced .

Comment: Please find the link to download : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.sun/com.sun.mail_1.4.2.jar.zip

Comment: Now its giving same type of problem -java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/Socket;
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
 and i thing i should show my code to you...

Comment: Problem is definitely with the class path. Edit you question to have your code as well. You can just put the line where you invoke the method.